# Managing large multilingual text blocks in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, content-management

In my Rails app, I have a number of pages that contain mainly a number of paragraphs with static content. The app is multilingual as well. So I tried the default approach: using i18n yml files, but the strings of text are just too long and maintaining them is too cumbersome.

So now I have simply created separate views for each language. But some of the pages are getting little more complex structure and so it's not a good idea to copy the structure to each language-specific view file.

I looked at Comfortable Mexican Sofa, but it seems that forces me in the same direction as my current solution: to copy structure to each translated variant of a page. And the problem seems to be that it is not really designed to work with pages that have some ruby included.

Summing it up, it seems I'm best served with a solution that allows me to manage my i18n yml files better. Maybe see all translations of one view in one page and allowing me to more easily edit the blocks of texts. Is there such a solution out there? Or would you suggest other types of solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at http://www.localeapp.com ?

Disclaimer : I co-founded Locale.

Comment: Currently no, you supply your own translators but we're working on a partnership with a translation service that would let you contract out translations directly from the app.

Comment: I was looking more for an in-app solution, but having scanned the landscape for viable solutions, Locale indeed seems to be a good alternative.